# What are best practices for on/off toggle on sensitive/adult content (specifically when it comes to photos) example included?

Tags: user-behavior, best-practice, toggle, content, photos

For example, on a website that has a gallery of Breast Implant procedures before and after photos, if the photos are blurred by default with an eye icon and users have to click on any one of the blurred photos which brings up a modal with information regarding the photo/patient/doctor/caption/etc and users have to click on the blurred photo to display the actual photo- is this good UX? If a site's primary users are on the older side and might not be tech savvy, would they know to click on the placeholder photo to display the actual photo they're looking for?

if there are users that don't know that they should click on the photo to toggle content on, how can we let users know what they need to do?

Sorry if this is confusing/ Here's a link to an example of what I'm talking about: https://www.realself.com/photos/breast-augmentation#

Comment: Hi, have you tested this functionality with your intended audience and asked them to think out loud? If so, what did they say?

Comment: no, i haven't. i'm just starting out with assumptions. this is kind of a random personal project and i don't have resources to conduct user research

Comment: @doubleddesigns I believe this is a common misconception; you don't need any significant resources to conduct basic user research. Ask 5 people in your target audience to navigate through your website and you'll have incredible insights into your design. Way better than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the approach of first masking the image and then clicking on an image makes it available, or click shows a warning where you have to click on Yes to see the picture (explaining that there is sensitive content). I think Facebook uses this approach.